# How do you print a specific cell from a csv file for a graph in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

this is the code i have

```
import pandas as pd
population_data = pd.read_csv("pop_data.csv",index_col="State")
population_data = population_data.groupby("State")["population"].sum().reset_index()
```

now if i type

```
print(population_data["State"])
```

then this is the output

```
0     AK
1     AL
2     AR
3     AZ
4     CA
.
.
.
50    WY
Name: State, dtype: object
```

I'm looking for a simple for loop code to just print the word "AK" or "AL" etc as the title for each graph separately

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure if it works

```
import pandas as pd
population_data = pd.read_csv("pop_data.csv",index_col="State")
population_data = population_data.groupby("State")["population"].sum().reset_index()
```

Then add `[0]` to the end of the code

```
print(population_data["State"][0])
```

If you want to loop through the States:

```
states = []
for i in range(len(population_data["State"]))
     # Either this
     states.append(population_data["State"][i])
     # Or the code to make a graph and the title
```

Now you can access all the states by `states[num]` where the num is the index of the states, starting from 0

Comment: thank you! what should i type if i wanted to make a for loop that would iterate through each State in the next line?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to loop through all the states? Already edited the code for the loop.

Comment: i'm trying to actually create a loop for a graph! i need each state to appear as a separate title on each graph, if you could help me with that

Comment: Do you want to appened them a list? Can you give a bit more details thanks.

Comment: so from your code i got the output AK
AL
AR
AZ
CA
CO
... etc  but i now need to create a code that will make each state a title for a graph for each different graph

Comment: I just updated my code, and you can access all the states by `states[num]` where the num is the index of the states, starting from 0